# Why isn't 'nullptr' in the 'std' namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

It seems that `nullptr` is declared in the default global namespace. Wouldn't it make sense for it to be in the `std` namespace?

Comment: Considering it is supposed to be used instead of null, reducing the required typing can only encourage its use.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`nullptr` is a C++11 keyword (no different to `if`, `public`, `true`, `void`, etc.), so namespaces don't apply.

Comment: More fitting comparision: `true`/`false`.

Comment: I think he said it just right. The `true`/`false` analogy isn't helpful for someone coming from a C background, as `true`/`false` in C are just macros defined in [stdbool.h](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdbool/) which do something like `#define true 1` and `#define false 0`. So, are you saying `nullptr` is a macro? Is it an integer, like C's `true`/`false`? Is it just a zero (`0`)?--that would kind of defeat the whole purpose of `nullptr`, now, so that analogy to C++'s `true`/`false` really really muddles things up.

Answer (score 29):

`nullptr` is a pointer literal the same way as for example `true` is a boolean literal. This literal has type `std::nullptr_t` that is as you see this type is defined in name space `std::` The pointer literal is described in section 2.14.7 Pointer literals of the C++ Standard.