# Expected unqualified-id before ‘nullptr’

Tags: c++, nullptr

I tried to implement BST but `std::nullptr` shows me an error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘nullptr’

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class BinTreeNode {
public: 
    BinTreeNode(T key): data {key} {
        left = std::nullptr;
        right = std::nullptr; 
    }
    ~BinTreeNode() {}
    T data;
    BinTreeNode<T>* left;
    BinTreeNode<T>* right;
};

template <typename T>
class BinTree {
public:
    BinTree(){ 
        root = std::nullptr;
    }
    ~BinTree() {}
    BinTreeNode<T>* root;
};

int main(){
    BinTree<int> tree;
}
```

I have tried searching it up in Google but nothing meaningful came up related to `std::nullptr`

Comment: Please don't edit "Solved" into question titles. Instead, accept the answer that was helpful to you (click the green check mark below the number of votes it has received).

Comment: Almost a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21510121/179910

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`nullptr`, unlike `nullptr_t`, does not need `std::` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21510121/179910). The reason for this is that nullptr is a literal, and is not defined in namespace `std`, same way 42 is not defined there. Nor it requires any include directives to be used.

On the other hand, `nullptr_t` is a type, defined in namespace `std`, and requires `<cstddef>` to be included.